# Submitting Forms Rendering On Different Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to make a form that has 2 inputs, for a title and enough space for a post (up to 1000 chars) but have no experience in react or jquery. Is it possible to get the inputs from create.html, and render a preview on home.html once the user has submitted, only using js?

## create.html

```
<body>
  <noscript>This site requires Javascript.</noscript>
  <header-plus></header-plus>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group" id="create-form">
      <div class="form-group" id="form-title">
        <p>Title:</p>
        <input type="text" class="titleForm">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="form-content">
        <p>Content:</p>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="What are your thoughts?" id="postInputForm" rows="30"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="input" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" onchange="openFile(event)"><br>
        <img id="output">
        <br>
        <script>
          var openFile = function (event) {
            var input = event.target;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
              var dataURL = reader.result;
              var output = document.getElementById('output');
              output.src = dataURL;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

          };
        </script>

        <button type="submit" id="submit-post" value="submit">
          Publish me!
        </button></div>
    </div>
```

There is a function for image upload but for simplicity I would just like to know if the content and title could be transferred to the home html

## home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- column1 -->
      <div class="col-8" id="recentposts">
        <post-preview user="" title="How to name a blog site" content="border radius"></post-preview>
        <post-preview user =""title="How to name a blog site1" content="aids"></post-preview>
        <post-preview user=""title="How to name a blog site2" content="pokemon"></post-preview>
        <post-preview user=""title="How to name a blog site3" content="yo yo"></post-preview>
        <post-preview user=""title="How to name a blog site4" content="content"></post-preview>


      </div>
      <!-- column2 -->
      <div class="col-4">
        <button id="createPostButton" onclick="location.href='create.html'"> Create Post</button>
        <div class="userPosts">Users own posts.....</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it. The simplest would be to have a function called `homeTemplate` that takes the inputs and returns `home.html` string populated with the vars using ES6 template strings. This can be called on form submit, so you need an event listener/handler. Then create a new DOM node based on that string, and replace the contents of `<body>` with that node.

Comment: If you want to get fancier and setup some client-side routing yourself, look into using hash (#) URLs and listening on the hash change event. Later on you can upgrade to using history API to make fancier, more natural routes (`/home` instead of `/#home`), but hash is easier.